# Porting over small JavaScript function with default values to Java

Tags: java

I am creating a fun little calculator program where you can give a sum and a set of other numbers and see all the ways you can add those numbers to get that sum.

For example if I want to see how to get the sum `12` with the numbers `2,4,6,8,10` I want the output to look something like this:

> [[2,2,2,2,2,2],[2,2,2,2,4],[2,2,2,4,2],[2,2,2,6],[2,2,4,2,2],[2,2,4,4],[2,2,6,2],[2,2,8],[2,4,2,2,2],[2,4,2,4],[2,4,4,2],[2,4,6],[2,6,2,2],[2,6,4],[2,8,2],[2,10],[4,2,2,2,2],[4,2,2,4],[4,2,4,2],[4,2,6],[4,4,2,2],[4,4,4],[4,6,2],[4,8],[6,2,2,2],[6,2,4],[6,4,2],[6,6],[8,2,2],[8,4],[10,2]]

I've done this in the past with javascript using this recursive function:

```
function f(A, N, r=[], s=N){
  if (s == 0){
    return [r];
  }

  result = [];

  for (let a of A){
    if (a <= s){
      result = result.concat(f(A, N, r.slice().concat(a), s-a));
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

You would call it using something like this:

```
f([2,4,6,8,10], 12))
```

Here is a JsFiddle of it:
https://jsfiddle.net/6u1v79Lb/1/

I am now trying to port this logic into java code but have not been successful. My knowledge of Java is not the greatest, but I have tried using different approaches using overloaded methods but have not been able to get close.

This isn't working code but where I am at with the logic:

```
 public static String f(int[] a, int n, String r, int s) {
        if(s == 0) {
             return r;

        }
    
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    for(int a_item : a) {
        if(a_item <= s) {
            //super confused what to do here
            Collections.addAll(result, f(a,n,r, s-a_item));
          }
    }
    
    return result.toString();
    
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your attempts at using overloading?

Comment: I am not sure overloading is the right way to do this. I've tried many different ways I just can't figure out. This is the latest thing I'm working on: public void f(int[] a, int n, String[] r, int s) {
  if(s.equals(0)) {
    //not sure how to return and array of arrays
  }
  
  String[] result = new String[];
  
  for(a_item : a) {
      if(a_item <= s) {
       //super confused what to do here
       [r.length + 1] = a;
       result = f(a,n,r, s-a_item);
      }
  }
  
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
  
 }

Comment: Added. It's not by any means anything that is working, but it's here I'm at right now.

Comment: To me, your function looks pointless and confused. Rather than translating it literally into Java, you should think about what you actually want to *do*, and then think about how to express that in Java.

Comment: Regarding `//not sure how to return and array of arrays`, your method is `void`. By definition, it does not return anything.

Comment: Consider using an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html). Instead of `concat`, use [`Collections.addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#addAll(java.util.Collection,T...))

Comment: @user I've updated the code, but it is still not quite working. If I call the following it returns an empty array: System.out.println(f(new int[] {2,4,6}, 12, new String(), -1));